# Why blocking code behaves better than non-blocking?

Tags: node.js, blocking, nonblocking

I have knocked up two little node.js snippets, that are doing the same thing, written in blocking and non-blocking ways, just to measure the performance diference. 
here goes:

non-blocking (the traditional node.js way):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  fs.readFile('lorem.txt',function(err, data){
    res.end(data);
  });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

blocking:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end(fs.readFileSync('lorem.txt'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

`lorem.txt` is just a text file roughly 33kb in size.

running `apache benchmark` on against both shows no difference, or sometimes better performance for blocking version.

`ab -n 100 -c 10 http://locahost:8080/`

blocking: `Time per request: 5.701 ms`
non-blocking: `Time per request: 8.401 ms`

Comment: is it possible that the file is in the cache after the first reading? which test did you run first? have you tried each benchmark a few times?

Comment: @TheBronx I thought about file being cached as well. so i first had a very small file, then gradually increased it to 33kb, not sure if itsa big enough. Yeah. I ran benchmark several times seqeuntually for each setup - the results are within 4-9mseconds for both, but most of the time non-blocking wins

Comment: interesting, this guy did the same test: http://afshinm.name/async-vs-sync-io-benchmark-in-nodejs/ but with a 1Mb text file and `ab -n 1000 -c 1000` but he got the expected results (asyn faster than sync)

Comment: I'll try that, however even with -n100 -c100 my core i3 machine was at 100% cpu on all cores (by NisSrv.exe under windows, which kept consuming cpu for few secs even after test was finished)

Comment: @dark_ruby I can confirm that using `ab` to benchmark nodejs locally on Windows 7 even with the standard "Hello World" example causes "Microsoft Security Essentials" (`NisSrv.exe`) to consume 100% CPU shortly after finishing. This lasts far longer the higher the number of requests value (`-n`) is.

Answer (score 4):

Asynchronous method does have better performance in a broader sense i.e. smaller response times for more (majority) concurrent requests.

The benchmark you did is a corner case. Suppose you increase the number of concurrent requests or increase the size of response returned. I am sure the synchronous method will perform miserably. Synchronous method is not good because of smaller response but bad because it is not scalable at all. An average modern day computer can easily handle read/writes at such scale. What if you increase the filesze to 1MB ? or requests to 1 million? Think about a server which has to deal with gigabytes of storage and serve millions of requests.

The core concept of node.js i.e. `asynchronous, non-blocking, event driven I/O` is built to solve problems of scalability like [C10k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem). The conclusion you come to is one-sided, I am sure asynchronous method will win 99% of the time in real world.

Comment: increased the file to 1Mb and `-c 1000 -n 1000`, async does win by numbers, but the difference is barely noticable

Comment: OK, but beyond this point async method will definitely perform better. The gap will become bigger and bigger.